# Selenium Webdriver - Unable to get focus back to child window

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium2

I have scenario where clicking on some link in parent window  opens a new window, after performing the actions on the child window, iam unable get back focus on the parent window, I have used the command `driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandle)` where parentWindowHandle is the window handler of parent window.
I have also used the SeleniumWebDriver backed command `selectWindow(parentWindowHandle)`
I am getting the error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 'auto_id' does not refer to an open tab (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.21.0', revision: '16552', time: '2012-04-11 19:08:38'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0-ea'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.21.0', revision: '16552', time: '2012-04-11 19:08:38'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0-ea'
Driver info: driver.version: TafRemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:175)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:459)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:463)
    at com.socialtwist.taf.webdriver.TafRemoteWebDriver.getScreenshotAs(TafRemoteWebDriver.java:22)
    at com.socialtwist.taf.selenium.TafSelenium.screenShot(TafSelenium.java:1008)
    at com.socialtwist.taf.testnghelpers.CustomTestListener.afterInvocation(CustomTestListener.java:36)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.InvokedMethodListenerInvoker$InvokeAfterInvocationWithoutContextStrategy.callMethod(InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.invokeListener(InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runInvokedMethodListeners(Invoker.java:579)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:727)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:846)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1170)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1147)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:749)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:317)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:274)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:223)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:974)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:905)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:203)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:174)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 'auto_id' does not refer to an open tab (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.21.0', revision: '16552', time: '2012-04-11 19:08:38'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0-ea'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
Build info: version: '2.21.0', revision: '16552', time: '2012-04-11 19:08:38'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0-ea'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:175)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:459)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:463)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.getScreenshotAs(ChromeDriver.java:149)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.CaptureScreenshot.call(CaptureScreenshot.java:36)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.CaptureScreenshot.call(CaptureScreenshot.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:151)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is failing in Chrome, but the same is working in FireFox browser.
I have used selenium-standalone-server-2.24.1.jar and Chrome driver 20 on Windows machine.

Comment: You say it works fine in firefox...  Which browser is it not working in?

Answer (score 2):

Any of these strategies should work

```
driver.switchTo().window(driver.windowHandles[driver.windowHandles.count -1])

driver.switchTo().window(driver.windowHandles[0])
```

Comment: Welcome to SQA.SE... An explanation to help future readers would help?!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't specifically tried it in Chrome, but what build of WebDriver are you running?  Have you tried updating to the latest to see if this is a bug that was fixed?

Have you tried

```
driver.switchTo().window(driver.windowHandles[driver.windowHandles.count -1])
```

? Or just

```
driver.switchTo().window(driver.windowHandles[0])
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` ?

Comment: If that works, I would like to understand why ;-)